# Handle input with unbalanced parentheses

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on an ANTLR 4 grammar which parses AST dumps produced by Swift compiler (`swiftc -dump-ast`).

See an example Swift program and the respective AST dump below.

Unfortunately, due to a [bug in the compiler](http://www.openradar.me/18904469) the dump may contain unbalanced parentheses (closing parenthesis is missing in some tree nodes).

Changing the `treeNode` rule as follows allows parsing such corrupted output:

```
treeNode
   : '(' treeNodeContent ')'
   | functionParameterListNode
   | '(' treeNodeContent
   ;
```

Unfortunately, this change also kills the parsing performance. Parsing time increases from **~50ms** to **~70...80s**.

The grammar does contain some ambiguities, but almost all the time is spent in the `treeNode` rule. Profiler shows huge amounts of lookahead and DFA cache miss rate.

Pinpointing the concrete types of nodes for which this issue occures and applying the fix only to those gave me parsing time of **~50s** (which is better, but still not good enough).

Here's the [complete grammar](https://gist.github.com/deville/d9579b374dd6a5d3590e3ef4279868ad), the [example program](https://gist.github.com/deville/5940ef9c8f41c3858bf9f3758a857d62): and its [AST dump](https://gist.github.com/deville/f2e2a3f941a7e7f58f7e2c19a64af5ef).

**Question:** Is there another way to handle unbalanced parentheses which doesn't affect performance?

Comment: Generating and then parsing debugging output, particularly unreliable debugging output (which is what the ast dump is) seems suboptimal when you can use SourceKit to directly examine the AST and thus avoid reparsing. Did you look at [SourceKitten](https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten) which appears to be able to generate JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Left-factoring would be my first attempt at fixing it:

```
treeNode
   : '(' treeNodeContent ')'?
   | functionParameterListNode
   ;
```

Comment: unfortunately, the result is the same.